# "Feature has conflicting event reciever settings" error

Tags: event-receivers, feature, visual-studio-2012, bdc

I am new to SharePoint so I apologize if this is not phrased properly, but I created a BDC to a SQL database in Visual Studio 2012.  I am trying to have the list created programmatically through an event receiver, but I keep getting the following error when I try to deploy the code:

`The Feature "Feature 1" has conflicting event receiver settings from the following items: DivisionSecurityRows, Feature1."`

I tried placing he code in the `FeatureInstalled` block, but that did not work so it is now in the `FeatureActived` block.

This is SharePoint 2013, if that makes a difference.  Thank you in advance!

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPListDataSource ds = new SPListDataSource();
        ds.SetProperty(SPListDataSource.BDCProperties.LobSystemInstance, "DivisionSecurityRows");
        ds.SetProperty(SPListDataSource.BDCProperties.EntityNamespace, "DivisionSecurity.DivisionSecurityRows");
        ds.SetProperty(SPListDataSource.BDCProperties.Entity, "Row");
        ds.SetProperty(SPListDataSource.BDCProperties.SpecificFinder, "ReadItem");

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                web.Lists.Add("Division Security", "", "Lists/DivSec", ds);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need me to show any additional code, please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. I was including the BDC module inside a feature that had an event receiver.  It seems that the BDC module references its own event receiver and this means that it can't be included in features that have an event receiver.

I fixed it by including the BDC module in one feature, and then creating an empty feature with an event receiver with all my code in.

Comment: I had the same thing but I was including a workflow in my feature. When I added a feature receiver in another feature I was able to deploy my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I hope by now you should have got your answer. In case not, below is the solution of the same. I am posting this now as I just now ran into the same problem, but fortunately, I could come out of it pretty quickly,and I think it would be helpful to all other developers like us.

Follow the below steps:

1. Go to Solution Explorer on Visual Studio
2. Open the Package file
3. You will see an erroneous entry (marked in red) in the package within the feature that you wish to deploy and is appearing on the right hand side (to be included for packaging)
4. Click on it and remove.
5. Close the package
6. Reopen the package file
7. Add the features back to be included for packaging
8. Build and deploy the solution.

Regards,
Neeraj